# Write code in app activities life cycle from a nativescript plugin

Tags: android, android-activity, plugins, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I know how to write plugin for nativescript and I know how to extend an activity with marshalling and js to run my custom codes in it's life cycle.

But imagine a case that you want initialize something at onCreate of app's main activity from your plugin. Is it possible at all? and if not, what are alternative ways?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. Simply listen to the activity callbacks from your plugin, but your plugin should have been imported at the very begging of the application.

```
application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, function (args) {
        console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", Activity: " + args.activity + ", Bundle: " + args.bundle);
    });
```

Or you could ask the developers to call a specific method on your plugin from this event, where you could do all initialisation (recommended).

Or the third option is to extend the activity within your plugin, but I would not recommend this as it will be a problem if user wants to extend his activity himself for some reason.